# HTML input text box scrolls up and down if drag with mouse

Tags: html, css

I tried to replicate the problem I'm having on my website with the below js fiddle but couldn't.

http://jsfiddle.net/YD6PL/116/

HTML:

```
<input class="givenLetters" type="text" value="h" disabled>
```

CSS:

```
.givenLetters {
width: 40px;
height: 40px;
text-align:center;
font-style:italic;
font-weight:bold;
text-decoration:underline

}
```

For some reason on the website when the user clicks and holds the mouse button they can scroll the input text up and down. It would be like being able to drag the 'h' in the js fiddle example up and down but still within the textbox.

What could cause this behavior? I would like the website to function as the js fiddle but can't figure out what would be different with the website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `box-sizing`, `display` or `line-height` properties come to mind if you're getting scrollable text. Open up a web development console (Firebug in Firefox or CTRL+SHIFT+J in Chrome), use the element selector to choose the element and then start disabling properties until the effect stops. Keep in mind it could be a combination of properties as well.

Comment: line-height did the trick for me. Thx for the debug steps too, I didn't know about the CTRL+SHIFT+J in chrome!

Comment: I'm happy to have taught you how to fish. :-)